# Variable matrix name in Julia-Language

Tags: matrix, julia

I try to create an optimization model a scheduling problem. The optimization model evaluates different data sets then return the optimal solution for one of the data sets according to specified criteria. To do that, I need to create a variable matrix name. For example,

```
x[1] = rand(2,2);
x[2] = rand(2,2);
```

I couldn't find in Julia-language documentation away to do that. So I am asking if there is a way to create variable matrix name? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by variable matrix name?
And are you using JuMP (you should be, it is great for this kinda thing)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a vector of matrices and index that.  Let's say you have 3 matrices: **m1**, **m2**, **m3**. Assuming you want to create a vector **v** = [ **m1**, **m2**, **m3** ].  Now, **v**[1] == **m1**, **v**[2] == **m2**, etc

If you have all of the matricies at hand when you create **v**, this works:

```
v = [ m1, m2, m3 ]
```

If you are obtaining **n** matricies one after the other, and need to add each one at a time:

```
v = Vector()
for i in 1:n
   m = get_new_data_matrix()
   push!(v, m)
end
```

Then **v**[1] is the first data matrix and **v**[n] is the last data matrix.

---

I agree with Lyndon White; if appropriate to your need, here are the [JuMP docs](http://www.juliaopt.org/JuMP.jl/0.15/).

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.